# Clever, interesting limits that can be solved with just calculus one techniques?

Tags: calculus, limits, big-list

Are there any limits that can be solved using the techniques learned in a calculus one class (so allowing things like L’Hospital’s Rule and the squeeze theorem, but not Taylor series expansion), but which are by no means routine/have an interesting trick to them?

I've seen examples where blindly applying L’Hospital’s rule gives an infinite loop, but those typically can be manipulated into a form where things are easier without issue; I'd like something a little more clever than that, but that a highly motivated calculus student could perhaps handle- the sort of thing that could be used as a fun bonus problem.

Comment: In particular interesting are those examples where L'Hospital fails.

Comment: (This is more a tangent than anything else, but it still makes me cringe that L'Hopital's rule is taught before Taylor series and manipulation of approximations, since the latter are infinitely more useful and completely subsume L'Hopital's rule...)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Hm, sure that there are not cases where L'Hopspital is useful or even necessary ?

Comment: @Peter if e.g. $f(a)=0$, $g(a)=0$, then L'Hopital's rule is just the first order Taylor series expansions of $f()$ and $g()$ around $a$: $f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+\ldots$, so $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)/g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}((x-a)f'(a)+\ldots)/((x-a)g'(a)+\ldots) = f'(a)/g'(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be limiting yourself, as limits where things like l'Hopital's rule break down *are* interesting/useful limits for students to do. Moreover, if you eliminate things like Taylor Series (which could make sense for a Calculus I student), you have eliminated another class of interesting limits. But there are still many interesting limits out there! But of course, to do an interesting limit may involve either specialized knowledge or giving the student a hint.

If you want to look through lots of such examples - with solutions - I'd recommend looking through many of the interesting limits people come up with on [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/) There you can find interesting limits like....

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+ \sum_{r=1}^n \dfrac{1}{3^r r!} \prod_{i=1}^r (2i-1) \right)
$$
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2020^{2021n} + 2021^{2020n}}
$$
etc. You may also consider looking through [old Putnam exams](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/) and seeing if there are any interesting limits that are at the level you desire - same with old Olympiad problems. But of course, these take the level of difficulty usually well beyond a typical problem you'd even give as a bonus (depending on your students).